# My c++ function is destroying variables when it shouldn't be

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct, delete-operator

The purpose of this function is to take a struct, and enlarge the array by 1. It does this by copying the array to a temporary array, deleting and recreating the original with a larger size. My problem is that when I run the function, all of my values within the struct become '-17891602'.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that this is the value that shows when the variable has been deleted? I can't figure out the problem. But here's the definition.

```
void Array::addValueStruct(int id, int size, int type, int compareValue, StoredData temp[])
{
    //struct
    StoredData* tempStruct = new StoredData [arrSize+1];
    for (int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        tempStruct[i] = temp[i];
    }

    arrSize = arrSize + 1;

    delete [] temp;

    temp = tempStruct;

    temp[arrSize-1].id = id;
    temp[arrSize-1].size = size;
    temp[arrSize-1].type = type;
    temp[arrSize-1].compareValue = compareValue;
}
```

Also, not sure if this is helpful, but the function call.

```
test.addValueStruct(5,5,5,5,testData);
```

UPDATE: Problem solved!

Comment: where is arrSize declared? who can u use it??

Comment: How do you call the function? How do you declare/initialize the variables you pass as arguments?

Comment: arrSize is declared globally, at the top of the cpp file. I don't believe this to be the problem because I've successfully used it before on a class array.

Comment: @WorldsWorstProgrammer `temp = tempStruct;` doesnt do what you want, because temp is a local variable. You would have to to declare tmp in the argument list as `StoredData* &temp` (that means reference to a pointer).

Comment: `I believe that this is the value that shows when the variable has been deleted?` There is no such thing. You made the assumption, and based your entire question on it. Unfortunately the assumption is incorrect. Try to avoid assumptions!

Comment: Don't add new questions. If you have solved your problem and encountered a new one, spend some time trying to fix it. If you still struggle in a few days you can always post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the array pointer is passed into the function by value. This means that when you reassign it to point to a different array, this change does not propagate back to the caller.

You need to pass it either by pointer or by reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `temp` by value. Therefore, `addValueStruct` gets its own copy and changes made to it are not visible outside that function scope.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is this line here:

```
temp = tempStruct;
```

Here you only changing the *local copy* of the `temp` variable. If you want to modify the variable used for the call you have to pass it by reference.